# URL Scraping and Displaying Output - Getting Output as $Array instead of value

Tags: php, arrays, url, screen-scraping

I am new to PHP coding, but familiar with the mechanism. I require a plugin to pull quotes from ASX (Australian Stock Exchange) for any company symbol specified in the shortcode.

I have completed the code and loaded the plugin on Wordpress, on frontend instead of showing the price for the company symbol it is giving output as "$Array", and not the value.

Kindly take a look:

This is my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'asx-prices', 'asx_prices_shortcode' );

function asx_prices_shortcode( $atts ) {

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'symbol'        => '',
), $atts ) );

// Obtain Quote Info    
$data = file_get_contents( 'http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/priceLookup.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes='. "{$symbol}" );

preg_match('/<td class="last">(.*)<\/td>/i', $data, $quote);

$output .= '<div class="asx_prices_symbol">Symbol: '. "{$symbol}" .'</div>';
$output .= '<div class="asx_prices_quote">Latest Price: $'. $quote .'</div>';

return $output;

}
```

And this is the output:

```
Symbol: QVE
Latest Price: $Array
Symbol: QVEO
Latest Price: $Array
```

And this is the intended result:

```
Symbol: QVE
Latest Price: 0.985
Symbol: QVEO
Latest Price: 0.038
```

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, I want to get involved into more PHP, that is the reason I got started today, I will need more expert help in the future.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match` returns an array. chances are `$quote[0]` will return the price.

try doing `print_r($quote);` and seeing if your desired result is in the array, and where it's located.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` put the results inside the `$quote` variable, creating an array.
You will find your value inside `$quote[1]`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php